# Receiving "LWR3008" error while accessing a LWC screen flow component in LWR sites

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, lwr, flow-screen-component

I am seeking assistance with an issue I've encountered. Within my current setup, I have an LWC component that functions as a screen component within a flow. This flow is called from another LWC component using the Lightning Flow feature. This entire system is hosted within the LWR Experience Cloud site.

While everything appears to function correctly when accessing this component within the Experience Builder, a problem arises once the site is published. Upon attempting to access the component in the published site, the following error emerges:

**Something went wrong with the "LWC_Demo" screen component on the "Report Adhoc Hours" flow. Contact your Salesforce admin about this error. LWR3008: Error loading https://demo.develop.my.site.com/volunteers/webruntime/component/latest/prod/en-US/c%2FlookUpWrapper**

On examining the Network calls in chrome, I can see the difference between the Experience Builder and the live site are

**Experience Builder: https://demo.develop.live-preview.salesforce-experience.com/volunteers/webruntime/component/latest/prod/en-US/c%2FlookUpWrapper**

**Live Site: https://demo.develop.my.site.com/volunteers/webruntime/component/latest/prod/en-US/c%2FlookUpWrapper**

While the component's JavaScript scripts are successfully retrieved and rendered in the live preview, attempting to do so in the published site results in the subsequent detailed error:

**GET https://demo.my.site.com/volunteers/webruntime/component/latest/prod/en-US/c%2FlookUpWrapper net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

**Refused to execute script from 'https://demo.develop.my.site.com/volunteers/webruntime/component/latest/prod/en-US/c%2FlookUpWrapper' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**

I've undertaken the following measures:

1. Relaxed the CSP setting.
2. Added the site to CSP trusted sites.
3. Enabled CORS.
4. Disabled Lightning Locker.
5. Exposed the LWC component to communities with the specified targets.

```
 <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>
    </targets>
```

What else needed to be checked? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this matter.

**Note:** It was working a while back not sure what has changed resulting in this failure

Comment: Did you get any fix for this issue?

Comment: same issue as here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396762/lwr3008-error-from-lwc-component-in-flow-on-a-digital-experiences-page

Answer (score 1):

This happens with LWR Experience Sites, updating the LWC is not properly reflected in the site. To fix this you need to publish the LWR site each time you updated your LWC embedded in flow.

Comment: Hi Damecek, I'm seeing this problem too with a newly created LWR site. I've tried your workaround but with no success. It;s a 404 error for the component that I see. Do you have any other insights on this problem?

Comment: Hi Keith, unfortunately this is the only solution I needed. So I don't have any other insight. You can try fiddle around with the api versions of flow or lwc, that is the only think coming to my mind right now.

Comment: Thanks Damecek - I may try that. I've opened a case and demonstrated the problem so will see if SF come back with anything

Comment: Great, let us know the outcome from sf support.

Comment: Hi Damecek, will do. Today's update is that it's being worked on.

Comment: Hi Damecek, Support didn't come up with anything significant. See my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416147/any-workaround-for-the-lwr3008-error-404-status-while-accessing-a-lwc-screen-f) for what in the end I observed but likely not relevant to what others have experienced.